# How to make the top part of a render less saturated/more pale?

Tags: compositing-nodes, color

How to make the top part of the render less saturated/more pale?
The Mesh needs more of a pale color in top part to match the background. How?

[image: 3D model no live action footage]

Answer (score 2):

You can do in compositing nodes.

Here is an example:

[image]

Node **Hue Saturation Value** can make your image more/less saturated, but you need to add a mask to specify on that part of image the effect will be affects. You can draw a mask, draw an image or like in my case, use a **box mask** node and blur it.

If you familiar with masks, you can draw a mask with feather, and use it, it gives more control of areas witch must be saturated:

[image]

Comment: This is not a gradient, right? Masking it out is a totally horrible idea.

Comment: @stjema why you think that?

Comment: The background image shows a gradient of saturation values. Not 0, and 1.

Comment: Top is white, and the more you go down, the more saturated the bg image becomes. Or not?

Comment: It depends how you setup box mask. Or if you want you can draw a mask in uv/image editor and use it instead box mask if you don't like it.

Comment: Oh. I now see this is a gradient! :D That is good

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a simpler method?

I will be using the [compositor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/introduction.html) same as in Crantisz's [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120994/2217) and we both are using the [Hue Saturation Value Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/hue_saturation.html) to desaturate the render, the difference comes in how I generate the mixing factor.

[image: compositing nodes]
Add a *Texture* node to the compositor.
Now head over to the *Properties* window, the *Texture* tab is the one we are interested in. After clicking the large *New* button, you will have a texture. First off change the *Type* to *Blend* (a gradient texture). Then down at the bottom set it to *Vertical*. (I find *Quadratic* is a nicer *Progression*, but completely optional.)

Back in the *Node Editor*, specify the texture you just created in the awaiting *Texture* node. Just click in the empty field, and a dropdown of the texture(s) will popup.

[image: Texture settings in the properties window]

That is it. You now have a gradient in the compositor.

---

To further refine the gradient go back to the *Texture* tab in the *Properties* window and enable the *Ramp* check box (encompassed in the yellow box in the image above.) With the *Ramp* enabled you can now tighten the end handles, add more color stops, reverse the direction, and so on.
You can see I moved the black handle towards the middle. That squashed the gradient, moving the start of the fade up, thus giving me more of the original image in the composite.